# Haskell compilation error

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

Im getting a strange error in haskell that points to the middle of the dropWhile in my debugger ex:
parse error on input '='
Failed to load modules.

Code:

```
identifyFilter :: String -> (Filter, String)
identifyFilter ('"':xs) | not null rest = (filter, rest1)
                        | otherwise     = error "Invalid input"
                    where   (field, rest) = break (=='"') xs
                            (cond, rest1) = break (=='"') (tail (dropWhile (/= '"') (tail rest)))
                            filter = ( FieldName field , identifyParsers cond)                      
identifyFilter ('@':xs) | not null rest = (filter, rest1)
                        | otherwise = error "Invalid input"
                    where   (index, rest)(reads xs) :: [(Int,String)]
                            (cond, rest1) = break (=='"') (tail (dropWhile (/= '"') (tail rest)))
                            filter = (FieldIndex index , identifyParsers cond)
identifyFilter (x:xs) = error "Invalid input"
```

I have no possible clue what could be causing the error a especially when it is pointing into a middle of a word.
If required more please ask.
Any suggestions would help

Comment: GHCi accepts that line for me (with `let` substituted for `where`).  The problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: A short, but complete code sample that produces that exact error when compiled would be nice.

Comment: Do any of the previous/following lines have an `=` above/below the middle of the `dropWhile`? If so, what are they?

Comment: I updated to add the full method, error occurs on line 5 col location on letter h of dropWhile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
where   (index, rest)(reads xs) :: [(Int,String)]
```

is completely broken, maybe `(index, rest) = head (reads xs :: [(Int, String)])`?? Anyway, that causes a parse error on that line or the following.

On another note, the conditions

```
| not null rest = ...
```

need parentheses

```
| not (null rest) = ...
```

but that should give a type error, not a parse error.

Comment: thank you! That helped, but for some reason there is another error complaining about indentaation on a line that doesn't exist...

Comment: Mixed tabs and spaces perhaps?

Comment: I tried every possible tab combination, I keep very strange errors every time, one was even something like at position 1:1, invalid input ';'

Comment: Make it all spaces, remove every tab from the file. And use a fixed-width font. Then indentation is unambiguous and you should be able to find the problem.

Comment: ok, I changed my notepad++ to write 4 spaces when tab is used, that helped a lot, thank you :)

Comment: @user1009731: You should consider using Emacs with Haskell mode or Leksah--editors like that can guess what the correct indentation can be. Using Emacs, I almost never have to think about how something should be indented.